# Three forms actions in one php page

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

Assume that I have a PHP page that has three forms.

1. Form one, it will ask the user to enter the email address while the code is hidden.

```
<label for="email">Email Address:</label> <input type="text" id="email" name="email">
<input type="hidden" id="code" name="code" value="42"> <input type="submit" value="Submit1">
```

2. Form two will be showing after step 1. In this step, the user will be asked to enter the code  in step 1 (which is equal to 42).

```
<input type="number" id="code2" name="code2"> <input type="submit" value="Submit2">
```

3. Form three, will be showing after entering corrected code in step 2.

```
<input type="number" id="code2" name="code2"> <input type="submit" value="Submit3">
```

How can I program it?

Comment: You can put the form `action` as the current URL, and add `if`s to the other forms, based on the stage the user is on. Is that a clear enough explanation?

Comment: If you can please support me with the code as I struggle with it. Appreciate your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this approach :

```
<?php 
function getFormContent() {
  $email = $_POST['email'] ?? null; //$email equals to null if it is undefined, to prevent errors

  if (!$email) {
    echo '<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email.." />';
    echo '<input type="hidden" id="code" name="code" value="42">';
  } else {
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="email" value="'.$email.'" />'; //keep email set after submitting first step
  }

  if ($email && $_POST['code']) {
    if (isset($_POST['code2']) && $_POST['code2'] == $_POST['code']) {
      //final form
    } 
    else { //second step
      echo '<input type="number" id="code2" name="code2">';
      echo '<input type="hidden" id="code" name="code" value="42">'; //we still need this in case user submitted a wrong code
    }
  }
}
?>

<form method="post">
  <?= getFormContent() ?>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: very nice. In case I don't want to show <input type="submit" /> in the final form, how can I do it?

Comment: You could set a variable (e.g. `$finalForm = true`) in the final form condition, and wrap the button submit in a `if (!isset($finalForm))` condition

Comment: Would it be possible to update it on the code please. Sorry for any incontinence caused you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to state the action of the form as the name of the file.
So, if the file you are working on is name `example.php` it should look like so:

```
$email = trim(get_variable_value('email'));
$code = trim(get_variable_value('code'));
$code2 = trim(get_variable_value('code2'));

//make sure to validate the input!! if it's not valid send back

<? if(!isset($email)){ //alternatively, you can add a hidden input `stage`. I just don't like it, as it can be bypassed.
?>
    <form name="transferToNewForm" action="example.php" method="post">
        <label for="email">Email Address:</label> <input type="text" id="email" name="email">
        <input type="hidden" id="code" name="code" value="42">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit1">
    </form>
<? } 
if(isset($email) && isset($code) && $code == 42){ ?>
    <form name="transferToNewerForm" action="example.php" method="post">
        <label for="email">Email Address:</label> <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="<?= $email ?>" readonly>
        <input type="number" id="code2" name="code2">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit2">
    </form>
<? } 
if(isset($email) && isset($code2) && $code2 == 42){ ?>
    <form name="finalFrom" action="theActualPageYouWant.php" method="post">
        <label for="email">Email Address:</label> <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="<?= $email ?>" readonly>
        <input type="number" id="code2" name="code2">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit3">
    </form>
<? } ?>
```

Comment: ( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ')' in C:\wamp64\www\form2\index.php on line 4.

This is in line 4 $email = trim(get_variable_value('email');

Comment: fixed. I was missing a `)` on the first 3 lines @HishamAlghamdi

Comment: sorry, got this error:
( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in C:\wamp64\www\form2\index.php on line 11

On this line:
    <form name="transferToNewForm" action="example.php" method="post">

Comment: right, I didn't include the <?php ?> tags. I'll edit in a moment @HishamAlghamdi

Comment: I still get errors:
Notice: Undefined variable: email in C:\wamp64\www\f2\index.php on line 18 Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0022238936{main}( )...\index.php:0 " readonly>

and

Notice: Undefined variable: email in C:\wamp64\www\f2\index.php on line 25 Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0022238936{main}( )...\index.php:0 " readonly>